# favicon not showing when opening in new tab

Tags: bug, status-norepro, google-chrome, favicon

Using StackOverflow in Chrome, sometimes when I open a question in a new tab, the favicon does not show. I haven't managed to track it down to any pattern such as specific links, it appears to be random as far as I can tell. I know it's a minor bug, but still a bug. All bugs must be squashed eventually.

---

**EDIT**

As people have hinted to, it could possibly be an issue with internet connection quality. I put this theory to the test.

Here is my internet speed test results (just one random test):

[image: SpeedTest.net Speed Test Result]

And here's the quality (ping) test results (just one random test):

[image: PingTest.net Internet Quality Result]

And my computer:

- Dell Vostro 220 Mini Tower
- Intel 2 Duo CPU E7300 @ 2.66GHz (minimally used during test)
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit
- 4GB RAM (minimally used during test)
- C: 57GB free of 132GB; E: 53GB free of 100GB; G: 71GB free of 465GB (3 different physical disks)
- NIC: 1GB Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

During this test...

- Killed any application which could interfere with CPU/RAM/NIC usage
- Completely shut down Chrome, then restarted only to open Stack Overflow
- Browsed various questions, right-clicked and selected "open in new tab"
- Observed 4 out of 20 "new tabs" randomly without their favicon
- Observed no pattern in which pages were producing issue
- The same URL when clicked twice might or might not produce issue either time

This at least rules out the possibility of internet quality. This building has a fiber line on a 10/10 speed, and a business Cisco network.

I've seen this issue even on our old network and internet connection which were entirely primitive compared to the network infrastructure now. I originally asked this back before we upgraded everything. I've also gone through a complete Windows re-install on both the computers I use since then as well.

Comment: I can't repro this. I browse SO using whatever is the latest version of Chrome a *lot*, and I've never seen the behavior you describe.

Comment: It's every once in a while. Like once or twice a day I notice there's no favicon in the browser tab for SO.

Comment: Try clearing your cache. In the meantime, this should probably be tagged [meta-tag:status-norepro].

Comment: I'd noticed this on Chrome 26.0.1410.43 twice today already. But it was because my connection was unstable at the moment.

Comment: Maybe the favicon was on your eye's [blind spot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_spot_(vision))? Just joking ;-)

Comment: "All bugs must be squashed eventually" I think back at this and realize I was completely wrong on that statement. This planet's ecosystem would collapse if every single bug were exterminated from existence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not something I have seen and I cannot reproduce. I am pretty much on SO and other SE sites all day long and am using the latest Chrome as well.

It is most likely do to connectivity issues (or browser issues) - either way, out of our control.